# Why is my comparison operator returning an integer, not true/false?

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I've got the following:

```
@d = {'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person', 'great' => 'remarkable'}

def find(x)
  result={}
  @d.each do |k,v|
    if @d[k] =~ /[#{x}]/
      #has to return in a hash
      result[k]=v
    else
      return {}
    end
  end
return result
end
```

With the input:

```
find('fi')
```

It should return:

```
{'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person'}
```

But I'm getting an integer. Through some IRB testing, it seems like it's returning `5`, but it should be true.

Edit: I should mention that, in this function, if something is input that doesn't exist, it should return an empty hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the `String#=~` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E), `String#=~` returns fixnum or nil. However `nil` behaves like `false` in conditions. The real issue here is that `return` inside the block will actually return from the method body.

As for the problem you are trying to solve, I'd just go with [`Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select):

```
 @d = {'fish' => 'aquatic animal', 'fiend' => 'wicked person', 'great' => 'remarkable'}
 @d.select { |k, _| k =~ /fi/ }
 # => {"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "fiend"=>"wicked person"}
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds. Gotta give it to you =)

Comment: If I load my file into IRB and run this method on a hash, rather than returning a new hash, it returns an Enumerator object. Using that same array, I get: `=> #<Enumerator: {"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "fiend"=>"wicked person", "great"=>"remarkable"}:find("nothing")>` -- Do I have to re-format that into a hash somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what version of Ruby are you using, but using my Ruby 2.0.0.p247, your `find( 'fi' )` returns empty hash (`{}`). Otherwise, using an instance variable (`@d`) at the top level is unusual.  What you want is the `select` method:

```
@d.select { |k, v| k =~ /fi/ }
```

Comment: I commented on @user2875767 's answer, but I'll leave the same comment here @boris-stitnicky: If I load my file into IRB and run this method on a hash, rather than returning a new hash, it returns an Enumerator object. Using that same array, I get: `=> #<Enumerator: {"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "fiend"=>"wicked person", "great"=>"remarkable"}:find("nothing")>` -- Do I have to re-format that into a hash somehow?

Comment: Try to copy this into your irb: `{"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "fiend"=>"wicked person", "great"=>"remarkable"}.select { |k, _| k =~ /fi/ }`. Otherwise, a result similar to yours can be reproduced by `{"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "fiend"=>"wicked person", "great"=>"remarkable"}.lazy.select { |k, _| k =~ /fi/ }`. So perhaps, somehow, your hash is lazy, without you knowing it.

Comment: Ah, I figured out what I was doing wrong. /[#{x}]/ returns the whole hash if it's empty, but /#{x}/ works well for me. I can't even replicate the Enumerator issue, but thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
newHash = @d.each_with_object({}) do |k, hash|
  if k[0] =~ /fi/
    hash[k[0]] = k[1]
  end  
end;

# => {"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "fiend"=>"wicked person"}
```

Or even easier:

```
@d.keep_if { |k, v| k =~ /fi/}

# => {"fish"=>"aquatic animal", "fiend"=>"wicked person"}
```

Comment: Sorry, but `#keep_if` modifies the original hash, which is not what the OP asked for.